# Woocommerce Hide Price Until Login - image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem using Hide Price Until Login plugin in woocommerce.
You can set password to show the price.

While i dont give the password on the front end, i cant see the product image.
I can click on the image and then i can see in lightbox, but on the single product page i cant see.

Somebody have an idea? :/

Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

In woocommerce.css, there is the code:

```
.product.has-default-attributes.has-children>.images{opacity: 0}
```

In your CSS file, change it to:

```
.product.has-default-attributes.has-children>.images{opacity: 1 !important;}
```

And the images will be displayed.